# Fit Correction on known distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, fitting

I'm looking for a way of correcting a linear fit through data.
The scenario is the following: 
[image]

In red you have data points, they are based on uniformly distributed points on the black straight line spread with a gaussian distribution.

The fit is visible in blue due to the effects on the borders of the distribution it clearly is not matching the black straight.

The question know is if there is a way to correct such effects, if the distribution is known?

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: which is your response and which is your predictor?

Comment: I want to find a procedure to compensate for the cut on the distribution which leads to the difference of the two lines.

Comment: You don't seem to have addressed the question. Your plot looks the wrong way around from the usual convention so I wonder if you're minimizing the loss in the horizontal or vertical direction, since that will affect discussion.

Comment: A I see what you mean. The response is here plotted on x and the predictor on y. This sounds strange but it is inspired by a physical experiment, where want to use this to calibrate our machine. So we test the machine with known y (energies) and get statistical fluctuating results out of the machine. I tried to switch x and y and the result is the same. Due to the ends of the distributions the fit is shifted. The only way I found to compensate this is to make the area of the uniform distribution larger (y from 0 to 100 instead of 0 10). This helps but is a problem for my application.

Comment: But your blue line is swapping the roles of predictor on the response?